# Drawing an oblique rectangle

Tags: java, swing, paint

I used this code to draw an oblique rectangle:

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    for (int i = 0;i < this.width ;i++) {
        Line2D line = new Line2D.Double(this.x + Math.sin(this.theta) * (width / 2 - i) + Math.cos(this.theta) * this.length / 2 
            , this.y + Math.cos(this.theta) * (width / 2 - i) - Math.sin(this.theta) * this.length / 2 
            , this.x + Math.sin(this.theta) * (width / 2 - i) - Math.cos(this.theta) * this.length / 2
            , this.y + Math.cos(this.theta) * (width / 2 - i) + Math.sin(this.theta) * this.length / 2);
        g2.draw(line);
    }
}
```

but output is for `theta = Math.PI/4`: which is more like barcode

[image]

can you help me show how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Why not `fill()` a `Shape` such as `Polygon`?

Comment: It worked.Thanks for your helpful guidance.

Comment: Glad to help; you can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188); your [mcve] may guide others.